# Swift: Assertion failure in UISearchResultsTableView

Tags: swift

I have a table view controller working in my project, attached to a custom class inheriting from UITableViewController. This table view uses reusable cells.

All was working fine, and I wanted to add a search feature, so I added the "Search Bar and Search Display Controller" object to the storyboard.

Now I get the following error when I click into the Search bar:

> ```
> *** Assertion failure in -[UISearchResultsTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:],
> ```
>
> /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3512.29.5/UITableView.m:6547
>       2015-11-11 16:26:24.212 Footy Vault[10420:2922226] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
>   reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register
>   a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a
>   storyboard'

I haven't changed my reusable cell identifier in the TableView, so I'm not sure where to go with troubleshooting this.

Any help would be MUCH appreciated!

EDIT: Cell for row at index path code:

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // **Method wide variables**

    let context = self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "selectedTeam", ascending: false)
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "UserSettings")
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    let frcu = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.accessoryType = .None
    let currentItem = teamsArray[indexPath.row]
    let teamName = currentItem.valueForKey("TeamName")!

    do {
        try  frcu.performFetch() //Fetch all entries in the UserSettings core data entity
        for us in frcu.fetchedObjects! as! [UserSettings] //For each item in the data entity, retrieve it as an object of type UserSettings and place into an array
        {
            let str = us.valueForKey("selectedTeam") as! String //Retrieve the name of the team from the entry in the data entity
            if selectedTeams.contains(str){
            } else {
                selectedTeams.append(str)
            }
            let cellText = currentItem.valueForKey("TeamName") as! String //Retrieve the name of the team from the entry in the array
            if str == cellText { //If the two team names match
                cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark //Apply a checkmark to the cell
            }
        }
    } catch {
        // Do something in response to error condition
    }

    cell.textLabel!.text = currentItem.valueForKey("TeamName") as? String //Set the text label of the cell to the team name
    cell.detailTextLabel!.text = currentItem.valueForKey("CurrentDiv") as? String //Set the detail text label of the cell to the team division

    return cell

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please post where you're calling `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`.

Comment: You should really be using `UISearchController` if your **Deployment Target** is 8.0 or greater as `UISearchDisplayController` is now deprecated. It isn't available in the storyboard but it's definitely worth learning.

Comment: Great, I'll give that a try. Irritating that Xcode includes deprecated features in it's storyboard builder.